# pyautogui workaround for wayland

Tags: python, pyautogui, ubuntu-22.04, wayland

From what I understand, `pyautogui` doesn't work properly when trying to get screenshots of my screen because I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 wayland.

I saw somewhere that you could enable Xorg again and it should work fine... however, this solution is not ideal for me.

Anyone knows any workaround for `pyautogui` to be able to capture proper screenshot?
Below my code to get the screenshot, but when I check the "test.png" file, it's all black.

```
import pyautogui as pg
x1,y1 = 1525,312
x2,y2 = 1655,370

img = pg.screenshot(region=(x1,y1,x2,y2))

img.save("test.png")
```

Comment: were you able to figure this our?

Comment: nope, but I haven't played with this since then... I am also having similar issues with sharing my screen when in a Zoom call due to Wayland (I believe)

Comment: Are you running gnome on wayland? Different compositors may use different mechanisms for screenshotting.

Answer (score 0):

know this is old but adding for reference for people googling this: run screenshot utilities such as flameshot that support wayland by

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["su <YOUR USER> -c '/usr/bin/flameshot full -p <FILEPATH>'"],shell=True)
```

One big problem is this runs very very slow.